# cross browser onclick issue

Tags: javascript

The remove function is getting called onclick in firefox browser, but not in chrome browser. Anything obvious going on here that I missed?

```
<button id="button_5875418" class="small-button" onclick="remove('5875418','0','551130','http://www.google.com');"><span><em>Remove</em></span></button>
```

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the fragment of code you have shown us. How are you determining that it isn't being called?

Comment: I have a breakpoint within the 'remove' function. It reaches the breakpoint in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. It would help if you posted the `remove` function or other related code where the problem could be occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was causing due to the function name that was being used. I renamed the function name from ‘remove’ to ‘removeItem’ and it works in Chrome now(as well in FF).Apparently ‘remove’ is a built in function in jquery that was causing the remove button to disappear in chrome instead of the calling the function we had defined.